# How can I install wordpress to run on my local server

Tags: wordpress, localhost

I've tried this over and over. Changed my config.php file everytime but my database information never seem to work right. How do I correct this? Thanks.

Comment: Please, add your code.

Comment: Are you trying to set up a new website or developing your already live website locally?

Answer (score 0):

To set up a new WordPress site locally, follow the steps below:

1. Download *MAMP* [here](https://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/).
2. Download WordPress [here](https://wordpress.org/download/).
3. Create a directory that will hold all your WordPress sites.
4. Open *MAMP* and go to Preferences > Web Server and change the root directory to the one you just created.
5. In the root directory, create a folder that will include a WordPress site.
6. Copy and paste WordPress files (from step 2) into the folder (created in step 5).
7. Create a database by going to http://localhost:8888/MAMP/index.php?page=phpmyadmin > Databases, adding the name of your choosing under Create database, clicking create.
8. Go to http://localhost:8888 and click on the directory that has your website.
9. Install WordPress. Enter "root" for both username and password. For database, enter the name of database you created in step 7.
10. Enjoy your locally-hosted WordPress site!